# Streaming using FFMPEG and custom codec

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

I'm new to streaming in FFMPEG. I have integrated a custom video decoder into FFMPEG's multimedia framework.

So, when i give the command:

```
ffmpeg -vcodec myCodec -i input.bin output.yuv
```

It generate a output yuv file. So this means that i have properly integrated my codec to FFMPEG's multimedia framework.

So, now if i want to stream a video using my custom decoder, how do i proceed? and for demonstrating both client and server on the same machine, what are the commands i shall use? I Think, since we have integrated custom codec properly, we don't need to modify any other thing. However, for streaming using custom decoder if i need to perform any changes in FFMPEG?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you only implemented a decoder, how do you want to stream the video using your codec? You'd need an *encoder* to do so.

Comment: @slhck: Thanks for the reply. Look my requirement is something like this: The server should send me an elementary bin stream, and client should receive this steam, decode it using my custom decoder and display it using ffplay. 
Please provide your suggestions on this.

Comment: Do you want to stream with ffmpeg, or would any custom solution work for you? Basically, you need to decide yourself how to transmit your stream over a network, e.g. through RDP/UDP or HTTP chunks, whatever you like. The client-side `ffmpeg` needs to be able to read from that format though.

Comment: Yes my requirement is to stream using ffmpeg only. And using the custom decoder, decode the receiving file and render it using ffplay. So if you have any steps regarding how to proceed, please put it in the form of answer. I'll accept it. -Tahnks for the reply.

Comment: @sam Custom codec? Can you show any way how to get started with creating custom codecs?

Comment: @nmxprime: Actually i'm given a custom codec(eg. H.264 is an open standard, anyone can implement it in the best way one can and so has my company done it). Now this Custom(because it is customized for some specific platform) codec has a set of API's using which i have integrated it into FFMPEG framework.

Answer (score 0):

for demonstrating both client and server on the same machine : use LAMP local server or any local server you prefer
to stream to that server just consider using M3U8 or DASH and use a directory from your server as an output .something like this :

```
ffmpeg -i input.bin -vcodec myCodec  -acodec myCodec  /var/www/html/output.m3u8
```

to watch your stream read this link http://localhost/output.m3u8 with an appropriate player(such as hlsJS) that can read m3u8 file types.